# Hundreds of CONFIG_CHANGE Messages in audit log

Tags: selinux

I'm using CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 with SELinux in Enforcing mode.  In my `/var/log/audit` directory, I'm seeing `audit.log` files with hundreds and hundreds of messages like this:

```
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1589975454.928:33143751): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 op=remove_rule key="privileged" list=4 res=1
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1589975454.928:33143752): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 op=remove_rule key="privileged" list=4 res=1
```

These files are starting to use up quite a bit of disk space.  After researching, all I can find is a description which says *config_change messages are "Triggered when the Audit system configuration is modified."*  This isn't very helpful since I'm not actively modifying anything on this system.

1. What "modifications" are triggering these messages?
2. Is there a way to suppress these messages?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the (generated) audit daemon rules (under `/etc/audit/audit.rules`).